# Implementing binary search in assembly x86 (stack corruption?)

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86

I am tasked with implementing a binary search algorithm in assembly (separate .asm file) and using it in a C++ program. I am certain I have correctly implemented the algorithm because I have stepped into the code, line by line, and it produces the correct results. But when control is returned from the assembly code to main(), an exception is thrown because of an access violation.

Am I mishandling the stack in some way?

**AsmBinarySearch.asm**

```
TITLE AsmBinarySearch Procedure (AsmBinarySearch.asm)

    .586
    .model flat,C

    AsmBinarySearch PROTO, searchValue:DWORD, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD

    .data

    .code
    AsmBinarySearch PROC USES edi, searchValue:DWORD, arrayPTR:PTR DWORD, count:DWORD

LOCAL first:DWORD,          ; first position
    last:DWORD,             ; last position
    mid:DWORD               ; midpoint

; Search an array of signed integers for a single value.
; Receives: Pointer to array, array size, search value.
; Returns: If a match is found, EAX = the array position of the
; matching element; otherwise, EAX = -1.
;-------------------------------------------------------------
    mov  first,0            ; first = 0
    mov  eax,count          ; last = (count - 1)
    dec  eax
    mov  last,eax
    mov  edi,searchValue        ; EDI = searchVal
    mov  ebx,arrayPTR           ; EBX points to the array

L1: ; while first <= last
    mov  eax,first
    cmp  eax,last
    jg   L5                 ; exit search

; mid = (last + first) / 2
    mov  eax,last
    add  eax,first
    shr  eax,1
    mov  mid,eax

; EDX = values[mid]
    mov  esi,mid
    shl  esi,2              ; scale mid value by 4
    mov  edx,[ebx+esi]      ; EDX = values[mid]

; if ( EDX < searchval(EDI) )
;   first = mid + 1;
    cmp  edx,edi
    jge  L2
    mov  eax,mid                ; first = mid + 1
    inc  eax
    mov  first,eax
    jmp  L4

; else if( EDX > searchVal(EDI) )
;   last = mid - 1;
L2: cmp  edx,edi
    jle  L3
    mov  eax,mid                ; last = mid - 1
    dec  eax
    mov  last,eax
    jmp  L4

; else return mid
L3: mov  eax,mid                ; value found
    jmp  L9                     ; return (mid)

L4: jmp  L1                     ; continue the loop

L5: mov  eax,-1                 ; search failed
L9: ret
AsmBinarySearch ENDP
END
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

// Function prototype for selection sort and swap functions
void selectionSort(int array[], int size);
void swap(int &a, int &b);

// Function Prototype for binarySearch()
int binarySearch(int value, int array[], int size);

// Function Prototype for the assembly language version of binary search
extern "C" {
    int AsmBinarySearch(int n, int array[], int count);
}

int main()
{
    // Local Variables
    const int SIZE = 10000;
    const int LOOP_SIZE = 1000000;
    int numbers[SIZE];
    int value;  // Value entered by the user
    int index;  // The subscript value of the matching array element or -1

                // Declare the starting and ending clock time variables
    clock_t startTime, endTime;
    double duration;

    // Define the array elements. Values will range from 1 to 1000.
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = (rand() % 1000) + 1;
    }

    // Prompt the user for a 3-digit number
    cout << "Enter a Positive 3-digit Number as the Search Value: ";
    cin >> value;
    cout << endl << "Please Be Patient. This may take several seconds . . ." << endl;

    // Validate the value entered by the user
    cout << endl << "Using a linear search." << endl;
    startTime = clock();
    for (int n = 0; n < LOOP_SIZE; n++)
    {
        index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            if (value == numbers[i]) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    endTime = clock();

    // Calculate the duration.
    duration = (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Display the results of the Linear validation search
    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "The number you entered is Not Valid." << endl << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The number you entered is Valid. ";
        cout << "It was found at subscript " << index << endl << endl;
    }
    cout << "   Elapsed time for the Linear Search was " << duration << " seconds." << endl << endl;

    // Sort the elements in the array
    selectionSort(numbers, SIZE);

    // Perform a Binary Search
    cout << endl << "Using the C++ Binary Search:" << endl;
    startTime = clock();
    for (int n = 0; n < LOOP_SIZE; n++) {
        index = binarySearch(value, numbers, SIZE);
    }
    endTime = clock();

    // Calculate the duration.
    duration = (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Display the results of the C++ validation search
    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "The number you entered is Not Valid." << endl << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The number you entered is Valid. ";
        cout << "It was found at subscript " << index << endl << endl;
    }
    cout << "   Elapsed time for the C++ Binary Search was " << duration << " seconds." << endl << endl;

    // Invoke the Assembly Language version of the Binary Search Algorithm
    cout << "Using the Assembly Language Binary Search." << endl;
    startTime = clock();
    index = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 1; n++) {
        index = AsmBinarySearch(value, numbers, SIZE);
        cout << index << endl;
        getchar();
    }
    endTime = clock();

    // Calculate the duration.
    duration = (double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    // Display the results of the Assembly Language validation search
    if (index == -1) {
        cout << "The number you entered is Not Valid." << endl << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "The number you entered is Valid. ";
        cout << "It was found at subscript " << index << endl << endl;
    }
    cout << "   Elapsed time for the ASM Binary Search was " << duration << " seconds." << endl << endl;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int binarySearch(int value, int array[], int size)
{
    // Declare and initialize the variable that will hold the subscript of the first element
    int first = 0;

    // Declare and initialize the variable that will hold the subscript of the last element
    int last = size - 1;

    // Declare the variable that will hold the subscript of the midpoint
    int middle;

    // Declare and initialize the variable that identifies the position of the search value
    int position = -1;

    // Initialize the Boolean flag that indicates whether or not the search value has been found
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && (first <= last))
    {
        // Calculate the subscript of the midpoint
        middle = (first + last) / 2;

        // Check to see if the search value is at the midpoint
        if (array[middle] == value) {
            found = true;
            position = middle;
        }
        else if (array[middle] > value) {  // Else, if the value is in the lower half
            last = middle - 1;
        }
        else {  // Else, the value is in the upper half
            first = middle + 1;
        }
    }  // end of while loop

       // Return the position (subscript value) of the element that
       // matched the search value, or -1 if the search value was not found.
    return position;
}

void selectionSort(int array[], int size)
{
    int minIndex;  // Subscript of smallest value in scanned area
    int minValue;  // Smallest value in the scanned area

                   // The outer loop steps through all of the array elements,
                   // except the last one. The startScan variable marks the
                   // position where the sacn should begin.
    for (int startScan = 0; startScan < size - 1; startScan++)
    {
        // Assume the first element in the scannable area
        // is the smallest value.
        minIndex = startScan;
        minValue = array[startScan];

        // Scan the array, starting at the second element in the
        // scannable area, looking for the smallest value.
        for (int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
        {
            if (array[index] < minValue)
            {
                minValue = array[index];
                minIndex = index;
            }
        }

        // Swap the element with the smallest value with the
        // first element in the scannable area.
        swap(array[minIndex], array[startScan]);
    }
}

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

Comment: You destroyed `ebx` and `esi` which are callee-saved registers. Add them to the `uses` clause.

Comment: Doh, I thought I had already added them. Thanks. Post your comment in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: To check stack put a breakpoint at the first instruction of your subroutine, and take a note where the `esp` points to, and the content of that memory (first dword is return address). Then put a breakpoint on `ret`, and let it run, upon `ret` check if the `esp` is pointing at the return address (and it's not damaged), and if the memory beyond that was not overwritten (that's caller area) (unless you write there on purpose, but you would know what to check then). (this is just general advice, Jester fixed your particular problem)

Comment: And also you may voluntarily create some kind of debug macro like "stack_canary_setup" and "stack_canary_check" and put them around function entry, and function exit, which will push into stack few canary values like `0xCCCCCCCC` (looks nice in hexa memory view, plus when executed by accident, it's opcode of `int3` instruction, which is used as SW breakpoint by debuggers) or similar, and then the check will test if they were not modified (stack overflow/overwrite happened), and there's correct amount of them (`esp` is as expected), and restore the stack before `ret`. Also arrays-canaries help.

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks. I did that and the 'esp' has the same value on entering the subroutine and right before the 'ret' instruction is executed.

Comment: You could simplify `shl esi,2` / `mov  edx,[ebx+esi]` into `mov  edx,[ebx+esi*4]`.  x86 has shifts of 0..3 built-in to to indexed addressing modes for no extra cost.  Similarly, I don't think you could keep all your variables in registers instead of storing/reloading to stack locations.  Use comments to keep track of which variable (`mid`, `first`, `last`) is in which register.  You can use `cmp` with a memory operand instead of loading with `mov` to reduce register pressure.

Comment: `L4: jmp  L1`.  Nothing falls into L4, so you should just put the `L4` label at the same place as L1.  Or name it something meaningful like `continue_loop:`  It's silly to `jmp` to another `jmp`.